# Can't use struct from own package

Tags: go, martini

I created following file structure in $GOPATH/src

```
bitbucket.org/MyName/ProjectName
```

I have follwoing files here

```
ProjectName
 - controllers/
    - meController.go
 - app.go
```

In app.go I'm importing my controller like that:

```
import "bitbucket.org/MyName/ProjectName/controllers"
```

And in main func I'm trying to use it's method.

```
meController = new(controllers.meController)
m.Get("/", meController.Index)
```

My meController.go looks like this

```
package controllers

type meController struct {

}

func (controller *meController) Index () string {
  return "Hello World"
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
./app.go:5: imported and not used: "bitbucket.org/MyName/ProjectName/controllers"
./app.go:12: undefined: meController
```

I don't have any idea how to get this to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Go, every symbol that starts with lowercase is not exported by the package. call your struct `MeController` and you'll be fine.

Comment: It's one of the most important idioms in Go, and same goes for struct members - it's a simplistic way of saying public/private. Some people like it, some people hate it. Personally I like it.